# Java FileNotFound Exception even when using absolute path

Tags: java, file-io

There are a lot of topics on this problem, but not one seems to have the answer I am looking for.  I am attempting to open a file for read/write, but I get the file not found exception.  I specified the absolute path, but to no avail.  When I check "exists" and "canread" both return false.  I have tried multiple files, and the result is always false.  Someone mentioned it could be a permission issue, but I don't know how to fix that.  Once more, if "exists" returns false, I doubt its just permission issues.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    File myfile = new File("C:\\Users\\Eric\\workspace\\ReadJPG\\test.txt"); 
    //File myfile = new File("C:/Users/Eric/workspace/ReadJPG/test.txt"); 

    boolean h = myfile.canRead();
    boolean p = myfile.exists();


    try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myfile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If you copy the path and paste it in windows explorer" what do you get?

Comment: As a sanity check, have you tried it without the C: in front?

Comment: Please try your check on each path component, starting with `C:\\`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path. The format you're using works. I tried to replicate, but could only by miswriting the file name. My code:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     File myfile = new File("C:\\Users\\iajrz\\Desktop\\usepass.txt"); 
     System.out.println(myfile.exists());
}   
}
```

prints true. Even if you had permission issues, "exists()" should return true if the file exists. Permissions wouldn't let you read, or write; they wouldn't forbid you from knowing that the file exists (i.e. listing). I tried.